# url-action mapping & routing in Spring MVC 3.0

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm developing a web application using Spring MVC 3.0 and looking for a ready-made solution, if any, or a "best practices" reference for a url/action mapping and routing system that can achieve the following:

- REST-friendly controller / method name to view mapping. The current mapping implementation translates the request to a view name, which may be problematic when using several parameters and is incompatible with REST urls
- A service that accepts the name of a controller, a method and arguments values and renders the URL that's represented by them
- Integration with Spring Security that can allow me to check for a given URL whether the current user is allowed to access it, so that I can decide whether or not to render a URL
- A menuing system based on the above that can define menues composed of these actions and render them to page

Basically what I need is the ability to define URLs in one centralized place, so that changing a URL (during development; I'm aware of the don't-change-live-urls idea :) ) does not mean looking up and changing that URL in a zillion pages.

Any directions to such an existing solution / tutorial / guide would be great.

Thanjs

Answer (score 9):

This is a feature I really miss in Spring MVC.
That's why I created the [springmcv-router project](http://resthub.github.com/springmvc-router/), basically a port of [PlayFramework's Router implementation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.0.3/routes) in Spring MVC (HandlerMapping + HandlerAdapter).

I'm heavily using it in several real-world projects and the Router implementation itself is reliable.

Comment: This looks awesome. Right now my routes are all defined in and spread across all the controllers and it's absolutely a mess.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [Spring Roo](http://static.springsource.org/spring-roo/reference/html/index.html). It utilizes many best practices for spring MVC, and it has a scaffolding feature that automatically maintains a menu, jsp's and all the CRUD methods of a controller.

Setting up Spring Security with Roo is as simple as typing "security setup".

Hope this is helpful.