# Dynamically extend Spring MVC powered REST api with access to application jar only

Tags: java, spring, rest

I am in a situation where I have a nascent rest api architecture where each method has tons of ceremony (validation, db connection acquisition/release, authentication), raw request/response objects as the parameters, and hard-coded json strings as the output. I want to use spring mvc to help with at least some of these issues (auth & db stuff i'll need to hold off on). This would render a lot of the current architecture unnecessary. This is pretty easy except for one feature of the current architecture: dynamically adding api calls.

The entry point (servlet) for the architecture reads from an xml file that contains the path for a request and a corresponding class to load. The class must implement an interface that contains an 'execute' method which has the logic for the request. The servlet calls this execute method after loading the class. This allows dynamic extension of the api as follows. The app is packaged as a jar together with the associated config (xml) files and given to a client. The client includes this jar in his project, creates a class that implements the aforementioned interface, and adds a mapping from request url to that class in the included xml file. He then runs the app and gets access to both the original api and his custom api.

Example:

Client is given app.war, interface.jar and custom-mappings.xml. app.war contains the implementation of the core api (rest webservice), and interface.jar exposes the interface BaseController that has the method 'execute' (app.jar also uses this interface in its controller). Client then defines his own class as follows.

```
package custapi.controllers;

public class ExtendedController implements BaseController {
public void execute(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
// LOGIC
}
}
```

He compiles this class and adds it to app.war. Next, he updates custom-mappings.xml with the following entry.

/custcall/mycall
custapi.controllers.ExtendedController

He then deploys the app. The controller provided with the core api receives the request /custcall/mycall, looks it up in custom-mappings.xml, finds the class is custapi.controllers.ExtendedController, loads that class, and finally runs its 'execute' method. This allows the logic defined by the client to be run.

Ideal:

Current architecture is replaced with spring-mvc. That is, there is no more 'super' controller that parses requests and delegates to the appropriate class and, finally, method. Spring handles this. For the app that uses this new architecture, the client would receive the app.war and the spring mvc deps that expose controller annotations. The client would then create a new spring mvc controller (taking advantage of validation, parameter -> pojo mapping, object -> json conversion), compile it, and add the resulting class file to app.war. His controller would then become an extension to the core api exposed by the app. When the app is deployed, he would be able to make a request /custcall/mycall like before and have it execute the logic he defined. This ideal scenario allows clean code for the core api (which I and others programmed) and an extended api. (A downside to this approach is that the client is tied to spring. In an even more ideal scenario, the client would use framework-agnostic annotations which are mapped to spring annotations by the app. I'm not sure how easy this would be.)

I'm not sure how the above would be realized with a spring-aware controller without sacrificing the benefits of spring. I don't believe the client could simply define another spring-aware controller (correct me if I'm wrong on this). The only solution I can think of is to have a spring-aware controller that has a wildcard path (e.g., /cust_rest/*) which acts exactly the same as the current controller. The client would not get any advantages that spring has to offer, but the core api would be a lot cleaner. I was hoping there was a better solution, however. Ideally the client would get the benefits of spring without having access to the core api source code. Any ideas on this, or is my solution the best that can be hoped for?

Thanks.

(NOTE: For both scenarios, I am only guessing how the client actually gains access to the dependencies/interfaces and deploys. I have only had access to the core api project for one day, and so my understanding of it is not complete.)

Related: [Runtime loading of Controllers for Spring MVC and dynamically mapping requests/URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19920912/runtime-loading-of-controllers-for-spring-mvc-and-dynamically-mapping-requests-u)

The above question looks pretty similar to mine. Replies are sparse (second one is just off topic, I believe).

Comment: Sorry but I find it hard to understand your question. Can you please give specific example of what you're trying to achieve

Comment: Apologies. I updated my post with a use case. I'll give an example of what I want to achieve momentarily (eating dinner).

Comment: I've added an ideal scenario to try to clarify.

Comment: Awesome. I'll give this a shot in the next few days. You should your comment as an answer so that I can pick it, assuming your suggestion works.

Answer (score 0):

Provided you setup classpath scanning properly there's no need for interface. Your clients can just annotate classes with `@Controller @RequestMapping("/foo/bar")`. Even if this class is located in its own jar it will still be scanned. If this is a REST service consider using `@RestController` instead to avoid having to place `@ResponseBody` on each handler method.

Use spring security to do declarative authentication & authorization (what you're doing now is programmatic security)